# jarsigner from jdk1.6 prints warning when signing jar. jdk1.4 doesn't

Tags: java, security, certificate, jarsigner

If I use jarsigner from jdk1.6 to sign a jar file, the following warning is printed:

```
Warning:
The signer certificate has expired.
```

If I use the same command to sign a jar file, but use jdk1.4 instead, the warning is not printed. I am thinking the only difference in jdk1.4 is that it does not show warnings if certificate is expired, but I am not sure if that is the only difference.

**Is this normal? If I sign with jdk1.6 will I have problems? Or should I continue using jdk1.4 to sign?**

These are the commands I used:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.4\bin\jarsigner.exe" -keypass mypass -storepass mypass Y:\file.jar myalias

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin\jarsigner.exe" -keypass mypass -storepass mypass Y:\file.jar myalias
```

Comment: *"Is this normal?"*  I'm not surprised at the result.  Sun/Oracle have been lifting the security reporting & requirements each Java version.

Comment: If I sign with jdk1.6 will I have problems? Or should I continue using jdk1.4 to sign?